# How to accomplish replicated calculation and plot in subset dataset?

Tags: r

I have a simulated data created like this:

```
average_vector = c(0,0,25)
sigma_matrix = matrix(c(4,1,0,1,8,0,0,0,9),nrow=3,ncol=3) 
set.seed(12345)
data0 = as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n =20000, mu = average_vector, Sigma=sigma_matrix))
names(data0)=c("hard","smartness","age")

set.seed(13579)
data0$final=0.5*data0$hard+0.2*data0$smartness+(-0.1)*data0$age+rnorm(n=dim(data0)[1],mean=90,sd=6)
```

Now, I want to randomly sample 50 students 1,000 times (1,000 sets of 50 people), I used this code:

```
datsub<-(replicate(1000, sample(1:nrow(data0),50)))
```

After that step, I encountered a issue: I want to ask if I want to run a regression model with the 50 selected people (1,000 times), and record/store the point estimates of “hard” from model 4, where is given like this:
model4 = lm(formula = final ~ hard + smartness + age, data = data0), and plot the variation around the line of 0.5 (true value), is there any way I can achieve that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest looking into either [`caret`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/index.html) or the newer (and still maintained) [`TidyModels`](https://www.tidymodels.org/) if you're just getting into R modelling. Either of these will make your life easier, once you get used to the `dplyr`-like syntax.

What you're trying to do is bootstrapping. Here is the manual approach using only base functions.

```
n <- nrow(data0)
k <- 1000
ns <- 50
samples <- replicate(k, sample(seq_len(n), ns))
params <- vector('list', k)
for(i in seq_len(n)){
   params[[i]] <- coef( lm(formula = final ~ hard + smartness + age, data = data0[samples[, i],]) )
}
# merge params into columns
params <- do.call(rbind, params)
# Create plot from here. 
plot(x = seq_len(n), y = params[, "hard"])
abline(h = 0.5)
```

Note the above may have a few typos as your example is not reproducible.